# Applying jQuery validation to a SharePoint visual webpart

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have a SharePoint visual web part in which I'm trying to use "HTML" elements in the page.

```
<script src="../_layouts/15/CreateInitiativesCSOM/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../_layouts/15/SP.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../_layouts/15/sp.runtime.js"></script>
<script src="../_layouts/15/CreateInitiativesCSOM/CreateInitiatives.js"></script>

<body>
    <form id="CreateForm" novalidate="novalidate">
        <label for="Workspace_Name">Workspace Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="Workspace_Name"/><br />

        <label for="Description">Description</label>
        <input type="text" name="Description" /><br />

        <label for="PeoplePicker">Owner Name</label>
        <spuc:PeopleEditor name="PeoplePicker" runat="server" Width="350px"
            AllowEmpty="true" MultiSelect="true" SelectionSet="User"  />
         <br />

        <input type="submit" name="Create Workspace" value="Create Workspace" onclick="createSite();" />
        <input type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset" onclick="this.Form.clear();" />
    </form>
</body>
```

I want to validate this form using jquery.validate.js

This is the code which i use to validate the form:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#CreateForm").validate({
        rules: {
            Workspace_Name: "required",
            Description: "required",
            PeoplePicker: "required"
        },
        messages: {
            Workspace_Name: "Please enter the Workspace Name",
            Description: "Please enter the Description",
            PeoplePicker: "Please enter the Owners for the Workspace"
        }
    });

    function createSite() {
         $("#CreateForm").valid();
    }
}
```

When I click the button it just post backs and nothing happens. How to resolve this issue?

Please help.

Comment: Your `form` element has no `action` attribute. What are you expecting it to do?

Comment: I have to validate the form, after which under "CreateSite()" function i will carry on the processing using sp.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should return false from the function

```
 function createSite() {
         $("#CreateForm").valid();
         return false;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add "return false" in your function, but as you're using jQuery you can even do something prettier:

```
$('#CreateForm').on('click',':submit',function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  createSite()
})
```

That way you bind your submit button with jQuery for the CLICK action. And then with `event.preventDefault()` you stop the default action of the brower (that is posting the form).